# Curious (possibly dim) question on ftp

Tags: linux, ftp

I am trying to use ftp to transfer the contents of 2 directories on my local machine (PI-jessie) to a website. The script successfully changes to the first local & remote directory and uploads the files. However the files in the second local are transferred to the first remote i.e. all files end up in the first named remote directory ('Data' rather than 'Plots').

```
ftp -p -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
lcd /home/pi/InfraSound/Data/2018
cd StarFishPrime/projects/infrasound/Data
mput *.mseed
cd StarFishPrime/projects/infrasound/Plots
lcd /home/pi/InfraSound/Plots
mput *.svg
bye
EOT
```

Comment: Does the secord `cd` actually succeed? I don't think it does as the path is relative to the current location. You may want `cd ../Plots`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have changed to the remote directory `StarFishPrime/projects/infrasound/Data`, the second `cd` will try to change directory to `StarFishPrime/projects/infrasound/Data/StarFishPrime/projects/infrasound/Plots` (relative to the initial directory at the start of the `ftp` session).

This will likely fail and the directory remains unchanged.

You may want

```
cd ../Plots
```

or use an absolute path.

Comment: @IanRobinson Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).